# How can I customize the 403 page for specific routes?

Tags: theming, routes, 9

On a D9 site, with an existing custom 403 page twig. I've been requested to show a different, variable, message from the "standard one" for a couple of specific routes.

I've tried with `theme_preprocess_page__403(&$variables)` but I couldn't determine the original route.

E.g. using `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName()` I got *system.403* instead of the route name I need to check. I've checked solutions to find the refer route but none of them seemed to work.

Actually the two routes that need this specific 403 are created programmatically with a **routing.yml* and relative controller in a custom module.

I wonder if it is possible somehow to specify the redirect path if the route *requirements* fails. I didn't find any documentation about, but that would another way to implements this requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 403 error page is not a redirect, so there is no referer. It's rendered in a sub-request which by default is using the route `system.403`.

From inside of the sub-request you can get the route name of the original request with

```
\Drupal::routeMatch()->getMasterRouteMatch()->getRouteName()
```